# How to make click event only active on name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function where I retrieve json data and when I click on one of the item names, it expands a description of the item.
One my html site it looks like:

```
Racket &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; $20.50
```

With a space between the item name and the cost.
The problem is, if I click specifically on the word "Racket" it will open up the description as expected, but if I click anywhere between the end of the letter "t" on racket and the last number in the cost "0", it opens up nothing at all.

Is there a way I can make it where the click function ignores everything after the last letter and or even if the click function works on the whole line as a last resort because at the moment, clicking after the letter "t" makes my page blank (it removes the item names, and doesn't bring up any description).

Thanks! Any help is appreciated!

```js
htmlEl.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  $("#pro").empty();
  console.log(event.target.textContent);
  for (var i = 0; i < prod.length; i++) {
    if (prod[i].name == event.target.textContent) {
```

Comment: What version of Java is this? It looks extremely peculiar

Comment: Please add the (html) code with so its clear what is used for `htmlEl` and `#pro`

Answer (score 0):

You can create an element around "racked". Eg.

```
<span id="racketClick">Racket</span>
```

and then add the event listener on this element instead

```
document.findElementById("racketClick").addEventListener('click', function(event) {...});
```